# Custom Directives and Template doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-template

I'm trying to make a custom directive that will show some elements that i previously declared in the MainController

HTML body:

```
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">

<h1> Choose your Car </h1>
<div  ng-repeat="car in cars">
<my-pattern info="car"></my-pattern>
</div>

<script src="js/MainController.js"></script>

<script src="js/myPattern.js"></script>

</body>
```

MainController:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController',function($scope) {
         $scope.cars=[
            {
                icon: 'imgs/lamborghini.jpg',
                name: 'Lamborghini',
                price: 100000
            },
            {
                icon: 'imgs/audi.png',
                name: 'Audi',
                price: 80000
            }
         ];  
     });
```

Custom Directive

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('myPattern', function() {
    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:  {
            info: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'js/directives/myPattern.html'
    };
});
```

Template:

```
<img ng-src="{{info.icon}}">
<h2>{{info.name}}</h2>
<p>{{info.price}}</p>
```

If i don't use the directive but i just make the output whit the expressions `<h2>{{car.name}}</h2>` like this it work but with the custom directive it doesn't show me nothing.
I have all in different files.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. There must be a issue with the location of your template with respect to your current HTML:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

angular.module('myApp').controller('MainController', function($scope) {
  $scope.cars = [{
    icon: 'imgs/lamborghini.jpg',
    name: 'Lamborghini',
    price: 100000
  }, {
    icon: 'imgs/audi.png',
    name: 'Audi',
    price: 80000
  }];
});

angular.module('myApp').directive('myPattern', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      info: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'js/directives/myPattern.html'
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainController">

  <h1> Choose your Car </h1>
  <div ng-repeat="car in cars">
    <my-pattern info="car"></my-pattern>
  </div>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="js/directives/myPattern.html">
    <img ng-src="{{info.icon}}">
    <h2>{{info.name}}</h2>
    <p>{{info.price}}</p>
  </script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved, i didn't synchronize the directives in the Custom Directive and in the body HTML. The code was right but i make a mistake with the calling script of the directive:

`<script src="js/directives/myPattern.js"></script>`